# Using sld in geoserver some states are not published

Tags: geoserver, sld

While publishing map in geoserver connection with postgres in style using sld from qgis validate error occurs but on removing units="mm" in the second line of code, some states are not being displayed on publishing map

sld file =
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" units="mm" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">   <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>district</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>district</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>first_stat is ''</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f7fcf5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ADJACENT COUNTRIES</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ADJACENT COUNTRIES</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ADJACENT COUNTRIES</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f7fcf5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f7fcf5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>                  
          <se:Name>DADRA &amp; NAGAR HAVELI</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>DADRA &amp; NAGAR HAVELI</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>DADRA &amp; NAGAR HAVELI</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e9c0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>DAMAN &amp; DIU</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>DAMAN &amp; DIU</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>DAMAN &amp; DIU</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e9c0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>DELHI</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>DELHI</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>DELHI</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e9c0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>GOA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>GOA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>GOA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e9c0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>GUJARAT</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>GUJARAT</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>GUJARAT</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a1d99b</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>HARYANA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>HARYANA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>HARYANA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a1d99b</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>HIMACHAL PRADESH</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>HIMACHAL PRADESH</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>HIMACHAL PRADESH</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a1d99b</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>JAMMU &amp; KASHMIR</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>JAMMU &amp; KASHMIR</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>JAMMU &amp; KASHMIR</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a1d99b</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>JHARKHAND</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>JHARKHAND</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>JHARKHAND</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#74c476</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>KARNATAKA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>KARNATAKA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>KARNATAKA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#74c476</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>KERALA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>KERALA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>KERALA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#74c476</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>LAKSHADWEEP</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>LAKSHADWEEP</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>LAKSHADWEEP</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#74c476</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MADHYA PRADESH</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MADHYA PRADESH</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MADHYA PRADESH</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#41ab5d</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MAHARASHTRA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MAHARASHTRA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MAHARASHTRA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#41ab5d</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MANIPUR</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MANIPUR</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MANIPUR</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#41ab5d</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MEGHALAYA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MEGHALAYA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MEGHALAYA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#41ab5d</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>MIZORAM</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>MIZORAM</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>MIZORAM</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#238b45</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>NAGALAND</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>NAGALAND</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>NAGALAND</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#238b45</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ORISSA</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ORISSA</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ORISSA</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#238b45</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>PONDICHERRY</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>PONDICHERRY</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>PONDICHERRY</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#238b45</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>PUNJAB</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>PUNJAB</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>first_stat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>PUNJAB</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#006d2c</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26000000000000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
```

Comment: remove units="mm" from line two to fix that, then please add the actual sld as text in the question instead of the picture.

Comment: after removing units="mm" from second line validate has no error bt on publishing map . kashmir and andaman & nicobar island, dadar & nagar haveli are is not displayed

Comment: please update your question with the SLD and a picture of the map

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Can you provide some examples of states not matching? Their name in particular.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this without seeing all of your data but I suspect that the states (?) that don't draw are not matching any of your filter elements. One way to check that is to include a `Rule` with an `ElseFilter` element so that it matches anything that doesn't match any of the other `Filters`.

```
  <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>Others</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>Others</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <se:ElseFilter/>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        .......
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
```

Comment: there are some mistakes in sld file ..now full it is fully published .. first i have to reproject india shape file then i link geo server to pgsql database and now it is published